# UIBarButtonItem not responding to touch after its UIToolbar has been animated

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uitoolbar, uiviewanimation

### Sample Context

First, for some context, all I am trying to accomplish here is have a `UIToolbar` appear above the keyboard when the keyboard appears. Here is what the scene is currently setup like:

[image]

*Note #1: UINavigationController should be marked as UIViewController in this photo*
*Note #2 `UIToolbar` was dropped into the `UIViewController` via `Storyboards`*

### The Problem

**The animation doesn't move the UIToolbar the first time I call my animate function.**

What happens is, my `-moveTextViewToolbarOnScreen` function is set to fire when the keyboard appears. The animation runs, and the `^completion` handler fires, only the `UIToolbar` does not move at all. So as a temporary workaround, I have a line of code in the animation's `^completion` block that checks to see if the `frame.y` of my `UIToolbar` is in fact where it should be (the animation destination), and if not, call the animation function again. **The mystery here is that the function always needs to be called twice in order for the animation to actually move the `UIToolbar` into place.**

Here is my animation function (notice the `if()` statement in the completion block):

```
-(void)moveTextViewToolbarOnScreen{

    if (self.textViewToolbar.hidden) {
        self.textViewToolbar.hidden = NO;
        self.textViewToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.26f
     delay:0.0f
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
     animations:^{

         self.textViewToolbar.alpha = 1.0;
         self.textViewToolbar.frame = self.textViewKeyboardToolbarOnScreenFrame;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

         // TODO: Figure out why this workaround is necessary. Sometimes the _keyboardToolbar doesn't
         // animate into place the first time and needs this recursive push.
         if (self.textViewToolbar.frame.origin.y != self.textViewKeyboardToolbarOnScreenFrame.origin.y){
             [self moveTextViewToolbarOnScreen];
         }

     }];

}
```

Moving the `UIToolbar` offscreen is fairly straightforward:

```
-(void)moveTextViewToolbarOffScreen{

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.3f
     delay:0.0f
     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
     animations:^{
         self.textViewToolbar.alpha = 0.0;
         self.textViewToolbar.frame = self.textViewKeyboardToolbarOnScreenFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { 

    }];
}
```

For reference, here is my animation destination `self.textViewKeyboardToolbarOnScreenFrame`:

```
 // 260 = keyboard height
 self.textViewKeyboardToolbarOnScreenFrame = 
      CGRectMake(0,
                 screenHeight - 260, 
                 keyboardToolBarWidth,
                 keyboardToolBarHeight
                 );
```

The animations are set to take place when the keyboard shows/hides itelf like this:

```
// textEditKeyboardAppear listener
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                       addObserver:self                                               
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)                                                 
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification    
     object:nil];


 // textEditKeyboardDisappear listener
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
   name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
   object:nil];


-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notifcation {
    NSLog(@"keyboardWillShow");
    [self moveTextViewToolbarOnScreen];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notifcation {
    NSLog(@"keyboardWillHide");
    [self moveTextViewToolbarOffScreen];
}
```

So can anyone help me understand why my `UIToolbar` wont animate into place the first time around, and needs an extra (recursive) call to my `-moveTextViewToolbarOffScreen` function?

**Any Ideas? I am stumped!**

*Note: Earlier I was also having a problem where my `UIToolbar` button's wouldn't work after the `UIToolbar` finally animated into place, but I solved that issue once I realized that I simply had another `UIView` frame clipping the toolbar view and was blocking the buttons from receiving any tap events.*